# AutoHotkey - How to use 3 different possible combinations?

Tags: scroll, autohotkey

I want to use these three hotkeys:
- left shift and wheeldown to scroll down twice
- left control and wheel down to scroll down 4 times
- left shift and left control and wheeldown to scroll down 8 times

This is what I have so far but when I input the commands nothing happens

```
Lshift & wheeldown:: 
GetKeyState,state1,LShift
GetKeyState,state2,LControl
if (state1 = d) and (state2 = u)
   send {wheeldown 2}
if (state2 = d) and (state1 = u)
   send {wheeldown 4}
if (state1 = d) and (state2 = d)
   send {wheeldown 8}
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my same answer in Super User

I would do it this way:

```
$+WheelDown::SendInput, {WheelDown 2}
$^WheelDown::SendInput, {WheelDown 4}
$+^WheelDown::SendInput, {WheelDown 8}
```

The $ sign is to prevent a loop where SendInput wheeldown would potentially trigger the same script over and over again since the user holds one of the modifier keys already.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! just 2 questions: what was the problem in my code and how come {wheeldown 2} and {wheeldown 4} doesn't get activated when I press both shift and control to use {wheeldown 8}?

Comment: You would probably need to use this: ~*wheeldown:: , The ~ will prevent a loop (the script calling itself) and * means that it will trigger based on whatever state the modifier keys are... Using LShift & will disable the Lshift key for any other control, to correct this you must add LShift::LShift.